# Can't create file. mkdirs() Always return false

Tags: java, file, return, mkdirs

I have that code, but I can't create file. configFile.getParentFile().mkdirs(); return false.

That works some time ago, I just export my project and that stop work without any reason.

```
    File configFile = new File(ProfessionalWarns.getPluginDataFolder(),
            "config.yml");
    if (!configFile.exists()) {
        configFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        forceConfigUpdate = true;
    }
```

All class (that code for bukkit plugin):
http://pastebin.com/hTPetAxu

Comment: Do you have write permissions for all directories on the path?

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak Hymm... that default path for saving all files for bukkit plugins, so I must have it, And that works some time ago... I just restart eclipse and... poof...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mkdir creates a directory not a file.  As you are getting the parent of a file, then calling mkdir on it, and it already exists, it is failing to create.  Because the parent already exists.

EDIT:

You probably want to do:

```
File configFile = new File(ProfessionalWarns.getPluginDataFolder(),
    "config.yml");
if (!configFile.exists()) {
    boolean fileWasCreated = configFile.createNewFile();
    forceConfigUpdate = true;
}
```

Comment: I also try that before, and any version don't work. I try test in one more time...

Comment: Tested... still this same.

Comment: If you are trying to create a  **File** and not a **Directory** my edited answer should work for you.

Comment: Hyyym, Big thanks because that works, but... that weird... I using mkdirs in 3 plugins... all works fine. Anyway... thanks

Comment: No problem.  mkdir creates a directory.  I'm not sure how that code could work for you but I'm glad its sorted now.